# webview guardar contraseña android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

tengo una aplicación web la cual la lanzo desde una webview en android, la pagina que se lanza es un login html lo que requiero es que el webview detecte la contraseña y la guarde para no volver a digitarla cada vez que ingrese a la aplicacíon.

este es mi código funciona perfectamente para abrir la pagina solo faltaria que recuerde el usuario y la contraseña como funciona en el navegador chrome.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
ProgressBar bar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    bar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebclient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.miappweb.html");


public class myWebclient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //* muestra ProgressBar
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Primeramente quiero comentarte que no es aconsejable guardar información sensible en tu aplicación, como son los passwords.

---

Una opción sería  el uso del método [setSavePassword()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSavePassword(boolean))

```
  WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
   webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
```

aunque su uso indica precisamente por seguridad que este método fue marcado como obsoleto en el nivel 18 de la API. El almacenamiento de contraseñas en `WebView` no será compatible en versiones futuras.

Answer (score 1):

Yo tambien tenia el mismo problema. Tenia una aplicacion web cargada desde Webview y tambien quería guardar el login del usuario psra futuras entradas.
Al final opté por usar Cookies desde la propia aplicación y un WebView que permitiera usar esas cookies.
Solucionado!!

Al menos, mientras trabajo en hacer una nueva app totalmente programada en AndroidStudio y Java ésta opción me funciona perfectamente.

Además de permitir el uso de las Cookies, tambien permite que tu WebView descargue archivos y los suba al servidor si lo necesitas.También elimina el STATUS BAR y permite ir hacia atrás si puede.

```
    package com.example.myapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadMa

nager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.myapp.R.layout.activity_main);


//-------------ocultar STATUS BAR---------------------------
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//------------------------------------------------------


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
//Runtime External storage permission for saving download files
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
        }
    }


    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());


    webView.loadUrl("http://la_web_de_mi_app.com/index.html");

        //--------------UPLOAD FILES-------------------
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        //-------------------------------------------






        //handle downloading
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
            long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Descargando archivo");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                    url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Descargando archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    assert webView != null;
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            //For Android 5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
            WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
            FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
            if(mUMA != null){
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                File photoFile = null;
                try{
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if(photoFile != null){
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                }else{
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if(takePictureIntent != null){
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            }else{
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Selección de Imagen");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Descargando archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
    // Create an image file
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
}
@Override


//------------PERMITE BACK CON BOTON DEL MOVIL O NAVEGADOR----------------------//
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(webView.canGoBack()){
                webView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Comment: ok, disculpa, lo corrijo en breve.

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar una clase como puente entre java y el javascript del `webview` para pasar la password desde javascript a java y luego encriptarla y guardarla en `SharedPreferences`.

En el ejemplo te muestro como pasar el dato y guardarlo.

El encriptado de la clave corresponde a otra pregunta y la complejidad va a depender de que versiones de Android vas a soportar.

**La página web en `https://www.example.com/login.html`**

Acá está el formulario de login.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PWD TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
        <p>Pwd: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"/></p>
        <p><Button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Submit</Button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**El Activity**

El `javascriptcode` se inyecta dentro del webview después de cargar la página con el formulario de login.

Usando javascript se obtiene una referencia tanto al `input` donde esta el texto con la password, como una referencia al `botón` de submit.

En el `botón` de submit se agrega un `event listener` para que cuando se registre un click, se tome el valor del `input` y se lo pase a la `clase java`.

```
public class WebViewWithJsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String PRF_FILENAME = "shared-preferences";
    private static final String PRF_PWD = "prf-pwd";
    private static final String url="https://www.example.com/login.html"


    private WebView wbContent;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    // Se inyecta al webview luego de cargar la página de login
    // Si ya hay una clave guardada la autocompleta
    // Al dar submit actualiza lo guardado.
    private String javascriptCode =
            "javascript:(function() { " +
            "  let btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');\n" +
            "  let p = document.getElementById('password');" +
            "  btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev){\n" +
            "    Android.savePassword(p.value);\n" +
            "  });\n" +
            "  p.value = Android.loadPassword();\n" +
            "})()";

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_with_js_activity);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PRF_FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);

        wbContent = findViewById(R.id.wbContent);
        WebSettings wbSettings = wbContent.getSettings();
        wbSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClient wbClient = new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if(url.equals(url)){
                    wbContent.loadUrl(
                            javascriptCode
                    );
                }
            }
        };
        wbContent.setWebViewClient(wbClient);

        // Acá se setea el puente a javascript. Del lado de javascript la api
        // se implementa con la variable 'Android'
        wbContent.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(this),"Android");
        wbContent.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void savePwd(String pwd){
        /* Encriptar aca */
        savePreference(PRF_PWD,pwd);
    }

    public String loadPwd(){

        String encPwd =  loadPreference(PRF_PWD);

        String decPwd = encPwd; /* Desencriptar aca */
        return decPwd;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    private void savePreference(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private String loadPreference(String key){
        return prefs.getString(key, "");
    }

    // La clase puente a javascript
    // Estos métodos se materializan del lado de javascript
    // Cuando se llaman desde allá se ejecutan en java acá
    // Los métodos visibles desde javascript deben estar anotados con @JavascriptInterface
    public static class JsInterface{
        private WebViewWithJsActivity ctx;

        public JsInterface(WebViewWithJsActivity ctx){
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void savePassword(String pwd){
            ctx.savePwd(pwd);
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public String loadPassword(){
            return ctx.loadPwd();
        }
    }
}
```